# Retrieving data from nested element

Tags: python, json

Good afternoon.  I am struggling getting the data from a nested element in a json response using Python.

The data returned from get is:

```
 "data": [
    {
        "id": "281474979309859",
        "name": "440",
        "gps": [
            {
                "time": "2022-01-11T18:49:11.065Z",
                "latitude": 42.18404771,
                "longitude": -83.240452259,
                "headingDegrees": 267.7,
                "speedMilesPerHour": 38.098,
                "reverseGeo": {
                    "formattedLocation": "21060 Pennsylvania Road, Taylor, MI, 48180"
                },
                "isEcuSpeed": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

To get the data I need I am using the following code:

```
while True:
## Get fleet data
response = requests.request("GET", url_fleet_location, headers=headers, params=params).json()

for vehicle in response['data']:
    for gps_ping in vehicle['gps']:
        if 'decorations' in gps_ping:
            odometer = gps_ping['decorations']['obdOdometerMeters']['value']
        else:
            odometer = None
        sql = "INSERT INTO tblUnitLocations(id, vehicle_number, lastUpdate, lat, long, odometer, location)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        val = (vehicle['id'],vehicle['name'],gps_ping['time'],gps_ping['latitude'],gps_ping['longitude'],odometer,gps_ping['reverseGeo']['formattedLocation'])
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        cn.commit()
        
        
params['after'] = response['pagination']['endCursor']
if response['pagination']['hasNextPage'] == False:
    time.sleep(30)
```

The issue is getting the data from the reverseGeo[formattedLocation] element.  All I am getting in my table is "o"

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `print(gps_ping['reverseGeo']['formattedLocation'])` within your loop and see if it is returning the correct values. We can't run your code as is.

Comment: not_speshal  It does indeed output the desired result.

Comment: I have no idea why it's working now but wasn't before but seems like it's working now.